# Clarifying a question

Tags: sentence-construction

I going to ask this question and please don't take it in a wrong way because lately my questions have been getting turn down and badly criticized so please reply only if you willing to help and please don't close vote this as I think it is helpful for a learner like me.

So here is my queston: Is it correct to clarify a question with a statement?

Let's say someone asks me this question: "Where were you living over there?"  and I mishear and then I reply to clarify: "Where I was living over there?" Would I be correct or should I reply with the same question they asked me if I want to make sure I heard right?

Comment: I would first say something like "Sorry I misunderstood you" or in my case (unfortunately) "Sorry my hearing is bad" before asking the question. Otherwise it could be misunderstood as inattentiveness. I would prefer to ask the person to repeat what they said, rather than guess what was said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Was" or "Were" are the past tenses of the verb "To Be". "Was" is used when referring to one's self with the pronoun "I", or the singular pronouns "he" and "she". "Were" is used when using "you", or the plural pronoun "they".

So, to clarify that a person just asked you "Where were you living over there?" You would reply, "Where **was** I living over there?"

This reference may help:
http://wasorwere.com/

Comment: That doesn't directly answer @Manuel's question, which was about whether he replies with a statement or a question. The answer Manuel is that you would normally answer with a question, so "Where was I living over there?"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that was @Manuel's question. Either way, you and I both have given him essentially the same answer.

Comment: @ColinFine thank you! You answered my question 100%

Comment: And to the rest thank you for replying to this thread you helped as well.

Comment: @BuffyOverflow you answer is just great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ManuelHernadez, you're very welcome!